# Wrong resolution with VGA, correct with HDMI

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, resolution, hdmi, vga

I have 12.10 installed with NVIDIA driver 304.43.
My card is an XFX GT 240.
Monitor is an RCA 32-inch generic 1080p television.

My problem is a VGA connection will only expose a maximum resolution of 1360x768, among other smaller ones, while a HDMI connection will give the proper 1920x1080. I don't want to use the HDMI however because there seems to be some weird dithering and poor color compared to the VGA connection.

I've tried both nvidia-current and nvidia-current-updates, I've also tried the linux header solution which pops up on Google everywhere. The proprietary drivers did not work either.

I know that the card and monitor are both capable of 1920x1080 through VGA because I had used this with WinXP installed.

I believe forcing the resolution should work since I know the hardware is capable. I just haven't figured out how yet; after trying about a dozen different solutions I found on Google, I still don't see any new resolutions exposed in nvidia-settings. Any changes to xorg.conf seems to be absolutely futile and ignored.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: I think you would be better off trying to troubleshoot the problems you're having with HDMI, because it is an overall superior standard and will fix a number of other problems.  Can you post pictures of the dithering and odd colours you're getting over HDMI?